# Help prove T is positive definite, if and only if $\lambda>0$ and $c+\frac{2\lambda}{3}>0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let **T**$\epsilon=c($Tr $\epsilon)$**I**+$2\lambda\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\in$Sym($\Bbb R^3$).

I am asked to prove **T** is positive definite, if and only if $\lambda>0$ and $c+\frac{2\lambda}{3}>0$.

I have been thinking nearly one hour, however I really have no clue for this. It is driving me crazy. Could anyone kindly provide a hint? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the inner product is not explicitly mentioned, it often means the usual one, i.e. $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$. Straightforward calculations show that if $x,y,z$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\langle T(A),A\rangle=2\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2) + c(x+y+z)^2$. So, you may try to prove that this expression is positive for every $(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ if and only if $\lambda>0$ and $c+\frac{2\lambda}3>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am confused why calculate tr$(AB^T)$, since the definition of positive definite is $xLx^T>0$. Could you please help explain?

Comment: and what if $x=y=z=0$, then it is always 0?

Comment: @Tony Oh, that's a small gap. Since $x=y=z=0$ if and only if $A=0$, we should consider all $(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ instead. It's fixed now. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Sherry Yes, a **matrix** $M$ is called positive definite if $x^TMx>0$ for all vectors $x$. Now, if we denote by $f$ the **linear map** $x\mapsto Mx$ and consider the usual inner product for real vectors, we have $x^TMx=\langle Mx, x\rangle=\langle f(x), x\rangle$. So, a linear map $f$ is called positive definite if $\langle f(x), x\rangle>0$ for all vectors $x$. This reformulation is more convenient because "vectors" are always expressed in a tuple form and the matrix $M$ is not always given.

Comment: @Sherry And this is what happens in your case. Note that $T$ is a linear map, not a matrix, and the "vectors" in question are $3\times3$ real symmetric matrices, but not tuples of numbers. So, instead of finding the matrix $M$ of $T$ and showing that $M$ is positive definite, I opt to prove that $\langle T(A), A\rangle>0$ for every "vector" (which is a real symmetric matrix here) $A$.

Comment: @Sherry As to tr$(AB^T)$, it is the standard inner product on $M_3(\mathbb R)$. If you [vectorise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) $A$ and $B$ and identify $3\times3$ matrices with vectors in $\mathbb R^9$, then tr$(AB^T)$ is just the usual inner product $\langle\operatorname{vec}(A),\operatorname{vec}(B)\rangle=\operatorname{vec}(B)^T\operatorname{vec}(A)$ on $\mathbb R^9$.

Comment: I finally understand it now.Thanks very much for your kind help!