# show that $\lambda(x+y+z)^2+2c(x^2+y^2+z^2)>0$ for any $x,y,z$ if and only if $c>0$ and $\lambda+\frac{2c}{3}>0$?

Tags: inequality

The question is related to this one
[Help prove T is positive definite, if and only if $\lambda>0$ and $c+\frac{2\lambda}{3}>0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431811/help-prove-t-is-positive-definite-if-and-only-if-lambda0-and-c-frac2-lam)
How to show that $\lambda(x+y+z)^2+2c(x^2+y^2+z^2)>0$ for any $x,y,z$ if and only if $c>0$ and $\lambda+\frac{2c}{3}>0$?

I tried to arrange the LHS to $(x^2+y^2+z^2)(\lambda+2c)+2\lambda(xy+xz+yz)$, and I take derivative to x,y,z. I found the minimum is at $x=y=z=0$, which has no information for solving the problem. I don't know how to proceed?

How should I proceed? Could someone kindly provided some help? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $≥0$? Because for $x=y=z=0$ the left hand side is equal to $0$.

Comment: @user109899  you are absolutely right. I need to prove that this expression is positive for every $(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ if and only if $\lambda>0$ and $c+\frac{2\lambda}3>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [strict convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) of $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, t\mapsto t^2$, you get that for all $(x,y,z)$ that aren't proportional to $(1,1,1)$, 
$$\left(\frac{x+y+z}3\right)^2<\frac13(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$
(and equality otherwise) i.e.
$$\forall x,y,z\in\Bbb R,\quad\frac13(x+y+z)^2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\text{ with equality iff } x=y=z$$

---

Hence if $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+\alpha(x+y+z)^2>0$$
for all $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\setminus \lbrace (0,0,0)\rbrace$ if and only if $\alpha>-\frac13$, which solves the question.

Answer (score 2):

For ease, let $(x+y+z)^2 = u^2, \; x^2+y^2+z^2 = v^2$.  Now

1) to show $\lambda u^2+2cv^2 > 0 \implies c> 0$ and $\lambda+\frac23c> 0$, it suffices to consider a case where $u=0, v > 0$ (for e.g. $x=1, y = 1, z = -2$) and then a case of $u^2=3v^2$, say when $x = y=z=1$.

2) to show $c> 0$ and $\lambda+\frac23c> 0 \implies \lambda u^2+2cv^2 > 0$, note that $3v^2 \ge u^2  \implies \lambda u^2+2cv^2 \ge u^2(\lambda +\tfrac23c)\ge 0$, with equality possible only when $u^2=3v^2=0 \implies x=y=z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat the equation as a quadratic in $x$ and consider the discriminant and coefficient of $x^2$, then solve the simpler problem in $z, y$. Fair amount of algebra but will work.